# HLSL num threads and dispatch (Vulkan), how to dispatch efficiently?

Tags: multithreading, graphics, vulkan, hlsl, compute-shader

I am writing a particle simulation in VUlkan using HLSL compiled into spirv with DXC on linux.

I am realising I have a miss understanding on how `numthreads` works.

Let me share a small snippet:

```
[numthreads(100, 1, 1)]
void main(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint index = id.x;

    simulate_particle(index);
    transfer_velocity_to_grid(min(index, 100));
}
```

When I do this I seem to be getting more than 100 threads so my index is going out of the requested bounds. On the other hand this is fine:

```
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void main(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint index = id.x;

    simulate_particle(index);
    transfer_velocity_to_grid(min(index, 100));
}
```

i.e. the above spawns exactly 100 threads. On the CPU side in both versions I am requesting a vector of (100, 1, 1) work threads per dimension. So it seems in the first version what I was doing was invoking 100*100 threads rather than just 100.

But of course with the version that works I am underutilizing the CPU.

I could declare an amount of numthreads of (100, 1, 1) inside the shader and only dispatch (1, 1, 1) work groups. But this has the problem that if the amount to dispatch changes at runtime I can't update it.

If the amount to send is always a multiple of `numthreads` then I could just dispatch `total_dispatches / numthreads`.

But if the amount of work groups I need is not such a multiple, I don't know how to efficiently dispatch my work groups. I would be either sending more or less groups than I actually need and in both cases I will run into errors.

Is there a way to send exactly a dynamic amount of work to the compute shader, spawn exactly that many threads and efficiently use the GPU to execute them?

Comment: You pass the number of particles as a uniform/constant and then you check if the index is bigger than that number. If it is, you skip the computations and avoid the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numthreads` defines the number of threads per workgroup.

The Vulkan `vkCmdDispatch()` defines the total number of workgroups. The dispatch function parameters can be changed at runtime to adjust the total size of the workspace; you don't need to change your shader at all.

Note that the size MUST be a multiple of workgroups, so if your problem space does not fill the work space, you need to handle the overspill (e.g. by skipping writes, or just writing dummy data to an overspill region, that you ignore later).

The optimal size of the workgroup depends on what you are doing. Single item workgroups may be fine, and allow arbitrary sizing of the problem domain, but you may want to match the hardware subgroup size for some use cases (e.g. if you want to use subgroup operations).

Comment: This answer seems to be ignoring the question, or I am not understanding. I am aware the total number of invocations will be numthreads * dispatch_size. The problem here is that the amount of work to do is not necessarily a multiple of the numthread declaration of the shader which seems to be a compile time constant. So it sounds like both you and the other comment said is the only way. To over invoke and waste computations by skipping the extras.

Comment: Correct, from the API point of view you must execute whole workgroups. If you are not doing any cross-thread computation then 1x1x1 workgroups are fine and allow arbitrary sizing, and the GPU should pack them together to fill the warp hardware. Just beware of divergent control-flow across branches within each subgroup.